# Interchangeability of cat and tomcat

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Are these two interchangeable? personally I never heard anyone saying **tomcat**

Comment: A tomcat is the male of the species.

Comment: @WeatherVane can I just say *cat* ?

Comment: The cat is male or female. The tomcat, or just tom, is male.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tomcat (or tom) is an adult male cat, (technically an unneutered adult male). A female adult cat is a "queen" and a child cat is called a "kitten".

You can use "cat" to refer to a male or female cat. "Cat" is the most common word. "Kitten" is also in general use. You should usually use "cat" or "kitten". The terms "tomcat" and "queen" are mostly used by cat breeders, or when the sex of the cat is relevant:

> — I saw a cat in garden today!
>   
>   — Was it that that tom that got my "Missy" pregnant?

The second speaker uses "Tom" since the sex of the cat is relevant. "Missy" is a pet cat's name.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "queen" in this usage.  The pairing that I know is *tomcat/pussycat*.

Comment: https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/04/19/male-and-female-animals/

Comment: @Gary 'pussy' is an informal name for any cat. Although it won't be straightforward to do an internet search for that sense of that word.

Comment: Well, [this source](http://www.dictionary.com/e/cat/) agrees with my native intuition.  "Pussy" is specifically feminine, even if its use is on the decline.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan  No. Your source contradicts you "Female cats (and often male cats too) are called pussies". Puss and Pussy can be applied to both male and female cats. However, your source does specify. "Cat fanciers will tell you ... female cats are called queens."

Answer (score 2):

A tomcat is a an adult, male cat.